# tkinter key binding causes image to disappear

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to bind arrow keys to buttons or at least the functions of the buttons (button_forward and button_back). The function of the buttons works, however, when I bind a key to the button the image just disappears.

It would also be awesome if someone could help me figure out how to create a loop to define the images and put them into a list. I'm just so lost when it comes to that.

The main purpose of the code is to be an image viewer that flashes an LED strip when an image changes.
I want to be able to control it using arrow keys to move forward and back between the images.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button,Label, DISABLED
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import board
import time
import neopixel
pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.D18, 30)

root= Tk()
root.configure(bg='black')
root.title("please work")

# define, load, show
my_img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("1.bmp"))
my_img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("2.bmp"))
my_img3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("3.bmp"))
my_img4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("4.bmp"))
my_img5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("5.bmp"))
my_img6 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("6.bmp"))
my_img7 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("7.bmp"))
my_img8 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("8.bmp"))


image_list = [my_img1, my_img2, my_img3, my_img4, my_img5, my_img6, my_img7, my_img8]

my_label = Label(image=my_img1)
my_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan= 3, rowspan = 25, padx=440, pady= 5)


def forward(image_number, event = None):
    global my_label
    global button_forward
    global button_back
    
    my_label.grid_forget()
    my_label = Label(image = image_list[image_number-1])
    button_forward = Button(root, text = "next", command=lambda: forward(image_number+1))
    button_back = Button(root, text = "previous", command = lambda: back(image_number-1))
   
    
    if image_number == 7:
        button_forward = Button(root, text = "next", state = DISABLED)
        
    my_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, rowspan = 25, padx=440, pady= 5) 
    button_back.grid(row = 23, column = 0)
    button_forward.grid(row = 23, column = 2)
    
    pixels.fill((255,0,0))
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pixels.fill((0,0,0))
    time.sleep(0.5)

    
def back(image_number,):
    global my_label
    global button_forward
    global button_back
    my_label.grid_forget()
    my_label = Label(image = image_list[image_number-1])
    button_forward = Button(root, text = "next", command=lambda: forward(image_number+1))
    button_back = Button(root, text = "previous", command = lambda: back(image_number-1))
    my_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, rowspan = 25, padx=440, pady= 5)
        
    if image_number == 1:
            button_back = Button(root, text = "previous", state = DISABLED)
    
   
    button_back.grid(row=23, column = 0 )
    button_exit.grid(row=23, column = 1 )
    button_forward.grid(row=23, column = 2)
    
    
    pixels.fill((255,0,0))
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pixels.fill((0,0,0))
    time.sleep(0.5)

    
button_back = Button(root, text = "previous", command = back)
button_exit = Button(root, text = "Exit", command = root.quit)
button_forward = Button(root, text = "next", command =lambda:forward(2))

root.bind('<Left>', back)
root.bind('<Right>', forward)

button_back.grid(row=23, column = 0 )
button_exit.grid(row=23, column = 1 )
button_forward.grid(row=23, column = 2)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bindings cannot work because the `event` corresponding to the keypress will be passed instead of the `image_number` argument in `back()` and `forward()`.

Also, you are recreating the widgets every time while you should only reconfigure them. So to change the label's image, you can do: `my_label.configure(image=<new image>)`. Also instead of passing `image_number` as an argument, I would rather use a global variable, so that it will be easier to use the functions in the key bindings:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label, DISABLED, NORMAL
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import board
import time
import neopixel

pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.D18, 30)

root = Tk()
root.configure(bg='black')
root.title("please work")

# define, load, show
my_img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("1.bmp"))
my_img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("2.bmp"))
my_img3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("3.bmp"))
my_img4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("4.bmp"))
my_img5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("5.bmp"))
my_img6 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("6.bmp"))
my_img7 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("7.bmp"))
my_img8 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("8.bmp"))

image_list = [my_img1, my_img2, my_img3, my_img4, my_img5, my_img6, my_img7, my_img8]

image_number = 1 
# create the label only once
my_label = Label(root, image=image_list[image_number - 1])
my_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan= 3, rowspan=25, padx=440, pady= 5)


def forward(event=None):
    global image_number   # global variable to keep track of the displayed image
    image_number += 1
    # change image in label
    my_label.configure(image=image_list[image_number - 1])
    if image_number == 8:
        # last image, disable forward button
        button_forward.configure(state=DISABLED)
    elif image_number == 2:
        # no longer first image, re-enable back button
        button_back.configure(state=NORMAL)

    pixels.fill((255,0,0))
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pixels.fill((0,0,0))
    time.sleep(0.5)


def back(event=None):
    global image_number
    image_number -= 1
    my_label.configure(image=image_list[image_number - 1])

    if image_number == 1:
        # first image, disable back button
        button_back.configure(state=DISABLED)
    elif image_number == 7:
        # no longer last image, re-enable forward button
        button_forward.configure(state=NORMAL)

    pixels.fill((255,0,0))
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pixels.fill((0,0,0))
    time.sleep(0.5)


button_back = Button(root, text="previous", command=back, state=DISABLED)
button_exit = Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.quit)
button_forward = Button(root, text="next", command=forward)

root.bind('<Left>', back)
root.bind('<Right>', forward)

button_back.grid(row=23, column=0)
button_exit.grid(row=23, column=1)
button_forward.grid(row=23, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```